# Adding legend to ggplot with geom_line with factor color and manually added line

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I can see that there are a lot of questions similar to this, but I cant find solution for my particular problem. 
Data:

```
risk_accum <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1465948800, 1465952400, 1465956000, 
                              1465959600, 1465963200, 1465966800, 1465970400, 1465974000, 1465977600, 
                              1465981200, 1465984800, 1465988400, 1465992000, 1465995600, 1465999200, 
                              1466002800, 1466006400, 1466010000, 1466013600, 1466017200, 1466020800, 
                              1466024400, 1466028000, 1466031600, 1466035200, 1466038800, 1466042400, 
                              1466046000, 1466049600, 1466053200, 1466056800, 1466060400, 1466064000, 
                              1466067600, 1466071200, 1466074800, 1466078400, 1466082000, 1466085600, 
                              1466089200, 1466092800, 1466096400, 1466100000, 1466103600, 1466107200, 
                              1466110800, 1466114400, 1466118000, 1466121600, 1466125200, 1466128800, 
                              1466132400, 1466136000, 1466139600, 1466143200, 1466146800, 1466150400, 
                              1466154000, 1466157600, 1466161200, 1466164800, 1466168400, 1466172000, 
                              1466175600, 1466179200, 1466182800, 1466186400, 1466190000, 1466193600, 
                              1466197200, 1466200800, 1466204400, 1466208000, 1466211600, 1466215200, 
                              1466218800, 1466222400, 1466226000, 1466229600, 1466233200, 1466236800, 
                              1466240400, 1466244000, 1466247600, 1466251200, 1466254800, 1466258400, 
                              1466262000, 1466265600, 1466269200, 1466272800, 1466276400, 1466280000, 
                              1466283600, 1466287200, 1466290800, 1466294400, 1466298000, 1466301600, 
                              1466305200, 1466308800, 1466312400, 1466316000, 1466319600, 1466323200, 
                              1466326800, 1466330400, 1466334000, 1466337600, 1466341200, 1466344800, 
                              1466348400, 1466352000, 1466355600, 1466359200, 1466362800, 1466366400, 
                              1466370000, 1466373600, 1466377200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
                              ), tzone = "UTC"), risk = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, NA, 
                                                          NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                          NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                          NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                          NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                          NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                          NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 
                                                          4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, NA, NA)), .Names = c("date", 
                                                                                                                         "risk"), row.names = c(NA, -120L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                      "data.frame"))
```

And code to generate graph:

```
    #color variable 
color_var <- vector(mode = "double",length = length(risk_accum$risk))
color_var[color_var== '0']<-NA
color_var[risk_accum$risk<6] <- "green4"
color_var[risk_accum$risk>=6 & risk_accum$risk<12] <- "yellow2"
color_var[risk_accum$risk>=12] <- "red"

#plot of Effective Blight Hours accumulation
ggplot(risk_accum)+ 
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = risk), color = color_var)+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "EBH accumulation")+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("green", "yellow", "red"))+
  geom_line(aes(date, y= 12), linetype= "dotted", size = 0.1)+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

I need to get a legend which would explain the traffic light system (red is danger, etc) and manually added threshold  risk  line.

Comment: sorry, missed that one line....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your color variable to the dataset, map to that variable inside `aes`, and use `scale_*_identity` to directly use the colors.

```
risk_accum$color_var <- NA
risk_accum$color_var[risk_accum$risk<6] <- "green4"
risk_accum$color_var[risk_accum$risk>=6 & risk_accum$risk<12] <- "yellow2"
risk_accum$color_var[risk_accum$risk>=12] <- "red"


ggplot(risk_accum)+ 
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = risk, color = color_var)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "EBH accumulation")+
  scale_color_identity(guide = 'legend') +
  geom_line(aes(date, y= 12), linetype= "dotted", size = 0.1)+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

You can also add your threshold to the legend:

```
ggplot(risk_accum)+ 
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = risk, color = color_var)) +
  geom_line(aes(date, y= 12, linetype = "threshold"), size = 0.1)+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "EBH accumulation")+
  scale_color_identity(guide = 'legend') +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = 2) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: I have just cleaned my environment and tried the code provided here, and it works. If you try the same it might work, maybe some other stuff you have loaded are in the way.

Comment: Add `group = 1` to `aes`. Like I said.

Comment: Thanks, it works, you should add the grouping argument to the answer. In my case it worked with separate color variable and not if I add it to data frame. Also I was not able to add the dotted line to the legend.